# Data Binding issue while navigation & routing?

Tags: data-binding, routes, navigation, sapui5

Today I faced a strange issue (could be a silly one) for data binding while navigating to 2nd view which is showing List of data coming from OData model and Panel at the bottom

I have replicate the code into this [`link`](http://plnkr.co/edit/ClZqvo?p=info) - `http://plnkr.co/edit/ClZqvo?p=info` (You can run this as well through RUN on the Top) - Kindly run it in chrome with disabled security (Due to CORS issue)

Now the problem is when I am navigating to 2nd view (OData Table) and then Select any List Item, you will see in the bottom, the Panel will reflect the selected item (as I have used BindElement method to bind the path). After this I clicked back and then my 1st view will appear (JSON table) again I clicked on Next Button and then 2nd view will appear again. When I select the same item which I have selected previously then this time Panel will not show the selected items. This issue is coming only when I navigate back and forth and select the same item. Not able to understand what caused this?

But if I choose any other item then it will show me the selected item.

Anyone having any idea about this?

~Rahul

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue when using `bindElement`, I have faced it too. It might be failing to resolve context of referenced entity. So, fields are not binded with respective values.

As a alternative you can use [`setBindingContext`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#setBindingContext) to bind fields within panel.

Since you are using named model, it should be specified as argument to `setBindingContext`.

So your code will be like

```
onSelect: function(oEvent) {
    var oContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("odataModel");
    var oProductDetailPanel = this.getView().byId("prodDetailsPanel");
    oProductDetailPanel.setBindingContext(oContext, "odataModel");
}
```